# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - add load balancer to app retroactively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I got a new domain and want to change my Elastic Beanstalk app name from `domain-name.elasticbeanstalk.com` to `www.domain-name.com`. When I created the EB app, I chose Single Instance.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.mikemurry.com/custom-domain-elastic-beanstalk/) to set up the domain. I selected my load balancer, but my domain seems to map to another app I have. This seems to be because I only created one load balancer with another EB app, and not the current app I am trying to map the domain to.

My questions are:

1) How can I use the single load balancer (associated with a different app) to point the domain correctly? This is probably not possible.

2) How can I retroactively add a load balancer to an existing EB app? Or do I have to recreate the EB app and add the Load Balancer at that point?

Comment: When you created the EB did you create using single instance or using Load Balancing, Autoscaling?

Comment: Single Instance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the two options you provided, I will suggest to use the second option.

- EB = Elastic Beanstalk
- ELB = Elastic Load Balancer

Follow the below steps.

1. Launch a ELB in AWS Console. If your EB instance is in a VPC then launch the ELB in the same VPC.
2. When you are launching the ELB attach the EB instance to that load balancer.
3. Then you can point your domain `www.domain-name.com` to that ELB using Route 53.

Or you can change your environment type from single instance to Load Balancing Environment. In this case, check below user Guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console

Comment: So I cannot change my existing EB app from Single Instance to Load Balanced